# Find all domains based on nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

How can I find all domains that use same dns nameserver, for example: `dns1-9.exampledns.com`

lets say there are 2 domains

```
abc.com
test.info
```

each of them has a NS record set to `dns1.exampledns.com`

Now. I'm looking for website/service where I can put `dns1.exampledns.com` and it will find me `abc.com` and `test.info`.

Any links, tips?

Comment: Product/Service recommendation are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this (in any meaningful manner) as the DNS system does not store this information. The only way to do it would be to do NS lookups for every registered domain.

Answer (score 1):

There are sites that make a business out of providing this sort of information but as it isn't actually possible to look this up in DNS (without a brute-force search) one cannot count on complete or up-to-date results.

As for how these sites collect their information, I would guess it's a mix of buying access to TLD zone data and providing other lookup services where users feed their service with domain names.

As an example there is https://www.robtex.com/#!dns=ns1.p01.dynect.net&rev=1 and I'm sure there are other similar services, both freely available and paywalled.